# How to schedule a request with Symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm making a website for a renter bike who purpose its bikes to differents places. I've choosen to use Symfony 4.

In my database (MySql), to be short, there are :

- a table KIND_BIKE(id, name, quantity...)
- a table RENTER_PLACE(id, name, adress, quantity...)
- a table BIKE (id, kind_bike_id, renter_place_id....)
- and other tables....

I've also a table DISPONIBILITIES with this columns : id, bike_id, date_begin_rent, date_end_rent, state (1->temporary_taked , 2-confirmed).

when a visitor is renting bikes, it will choose in first step the dates of its rent. At this moment, a ID is created for the rent (id_reservation).
Next it will can choose its bikes. After the visitor add to its cart a bike, a row in the table DISPONIBLITIES  is created with the id_reservation and the state 1.

If the visitor confirms its rent, all of rows in DISPONIBILITIES which created for this rent will be updated (state 1 to state 2).

But i don't know what to do for rows will be inserted and the visitor doesn't confirm its rent and leaves its web navigator....

My question is if Symfony is able to schedule in the 15minutes which follow the row's creation a request which wills erase rows for whom the state is equal to 1 and have the good id_reservation ?

If it's possible, what is the symfony's component that i will to use to do this?

Comment: Please show us some code. SO does not work like this or bring a specific issue you are facing which fits the [remit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of this site.

Comment: You can use the `Console Component` with a `cron job` executed every minute to check if unconfirmed reservations were inserted for more than 15 minutes

Comment: @JulienBourdic your awser it's very interisting ! I have to research some informations but thank you ! i will no forgive to add the tag solved if it's worked ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should only persist in the database with complete data. Intermediate booking steps should simply be saved in the visitor's session. At the end of the process, you persist in the database. I think you should create a "BookingManager" service that you call in your controller to save in session as the user progresses.

Comment: This not answer his question. He probably has to block a bike in DB during the checkout tunnel to avoid stock problem.

Comment: Thank you but your idea doesn't solve my problematic.... because the bike is save is the session and not in my database... the bike can be rent by an other visitor.

Comment: an other solution: You can add a datetime field in your bike entity. When a user starts the booking process, a listener updates it with the current date. A bike can be available for booking if the datetime field is older than a timout you have defined.